# nuget push timeouts after 5 minutes in Azure DevOps

Tags: node.js, azure, nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to publish my node application using NuGet and Azure DevOps.

Client requires to pack `node_modules` together with source code, so that application can be used without installing dependencies on host.

Here is part of `azure-pipelines.yml` responsible for pushing package:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: "Publish the artifacts"
  inputs:
    command: push
    packagesToPush: "path-to-package.nupkg"
    nuGetFeedType: internal
    publishVstsFeed: "SomeFeed"
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: BuildNumber
    verbosityPush: "Detailed"
    arguments: "-Timeout 901"
```

Docs say that i can use `arguments` field to pass parameters to the command, but it seems it it ignored and push command always times out after 5 minutes (or 300 seconds - that is default timeout)

There is no information in the docs about format of `arguments` field, I just assumed it should be a string.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check the logs carefully? I'm wondering if authentication is not set up correctly, and nuget.exe is waiting for someone to interactively type in the username and password, which obviously isn't going to happen in a CI build. Look carefully if there is anything that looks like it's asking for a username or password, so see if that's causing the timeout.

Comment: @zivkan the build is running in non-interactive mode. What I've found is that `nuget pack` works when packing fewer files, so probably it's the problem with package size (its around 200MB). In nuget push you can specify -Timeout option, but can't find how to pass it through azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  According to the logs and error message, the solution is to add -Timeout NUMSECS to the nuget command line.  It appears you can't just add this argument.  You have to switch the DevOps task from push to custom and then roll the entire command line yourself.  Now instead of just adding a timeout arg, you have to go figure out the entire command line needed which is more involved.  The task has a general timeout which is not used.  I'm stuck on this also at this point.

Comment: @Nerdtron thanks for the suggestion, will try it out. As for now, I have identified that the problem is package size. I was able to split the package into 2 packages and copy necessary files using "content files". Also, I used pkg.js to pack and compress my dependencies and source code into one executable. That lowered the package size significantly. Now, when deploying two NuGet packages, I no longer receive a timeout error.